# Trying to get the user to choose an operation they want to use and then run the respective program

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu

Trying to get the user to choose an operation they want to use and then run the respective program. Don't get what is the problem here?

This is my code

```
from collections import Counter
print (30 * '-')
print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
print (30 * '-')
print ("Program 1.Total Populations of the different continents")
print ("Program 2.Percentage Change(%) for different countries")
print (30 * '-')

Input1=1
Input2=2

## Get input ###
choice = int(input('Enter your choice [1-2] : '))

### Take action as per selected menu-option ###
while choice==1 or choice==2:
    if (choice == 1):
        counter1 = Counter()
    with open('a.txt') as f:
        for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split(';')
            population = int(splits[3])
            continent = splits[-1].strip()
            counter1[continent] += population
# Print continents sorted by population
    for continent, pop_sum in counter1.most_common():
       print(continent, ":", pop_sum)

    else:
        counter2 = Counter()
    with open("a.txt") as f:
        for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split(';')
            change = float(splits[6])
            country = splits[1].strip()
            counter2[country] += change      
    #Percentage Change By Countries"
    print()
    print ("Percentage Change By Countries")
    for country, change_sum in counter2.most_common():
        print(country, change_sum,"%")
```

Sample Data
World Population Data 2019 from the United Nations
Rank; Country; 2018; 2019; % Share; Pop Change; % Change; Continent
1; China; 1427647786; 1433783686; 18.6; 6135900; 0.43; Asia
2; India; 1352642280; 1366417754; 17.7; 13775474; 1.02; Asia
3; United States of America; 327096265; 329064917; 4.27; 1968652; 0.60; North America
4; Indonesia; 267670543; 270625568; 3.51; 2955025; 1.10; Asia
5; Pakistan; 212228286; 216565318; 2.81; 4337032; 2.04; Asia
6; Brazil; 209469323; 211049527; 2.74; 1580204; 0.75; South America
7; Nigeria; 195874683; 200963599; 2.61; 5088916; 2.60; Africa
8; Bangladesh; 161376708; 163046161; 2.11; 1669453; 1.03; Asia
9; Russian Federation; 145734038; 145872256; 1.89; 138218; 0.09; Europe
10; Mexico; 126190788; 127575529; 1.65; 1384741; 1.10; North America

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i didn't really understand what you want, but i corrected your indentation problems.

```
from collections import Counter

print (30 * '-')
print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
print (30 * '-')
print ("1.Total Populations of the different continents")
print ("2.Percentage Change(%) for different countries")
print (30 * '-')

## Get input ###
choice = int(input('Enter your choice [1-2] : '))

### Take action as per selected menu-option ###

#1st Operation
print ("Continents Sorted By Population")
while choice==1 or choice==2:
    if (choice == 1):
        counter1 = Counter()
        with open('a.txt') as f:
            for i in range(0,2):
                next(f)
            for line in f:
                splits = line.split(';')
                population = int(splits[3])
                continent = splits[-1].strip()
                counter1[continent] += population
        # Print continents sorted by population
        for continent, pop_sum in counter1.most_common():
             print(continent, ":", pop_sum)

#2nd operation
#Percentage Change By Countries
    elif choice==2:
        counter2 = Counter()
        with open("a.txt") as f:
            for i in range(0,2):
                next(f)
            for line in f:
                splits = line.split(';')
                change = float(splits[6])
                country = splits[1].strip()
                counter2[country] += change
print()

print ("Percentage Change By Countries")
for country, change_sum in counter2.most_common():
    print(country, change_sum,"%")
```

Comment: hi i just edited my original code,hope it helps to solve my qn...thanks btw!